# WordPress > Calling "Recent Posts" widget via script from custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried to code a recent posts script for my custom WP theme, however, it occurs to me that since WP ships with a recent posts widget, ideally I should just be able to call that from within my sidebar.php script, passing it the "Number of posts to show" parameter.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query API WordPress offers: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

Example:

```
<?php
    $myQuery = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'nopaging'    => true,
            'post_type'   => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_count'  => 5
        )
    );

    if ( $myQuery->have_posts() )
    {
        while ( $myQuery->have_posts() )
        {
            $post = $myQuery->next_post();
            ?>
    Do whatever you want …
    To test for the current page:
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
    <?php
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == str_replace(
            'http'
                . ( empty ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? '' : 's' )
                . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '',
            get_permalink()
        ) )
    {
        print ' class="current"';
    }
    ?>
    ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks toscho. Do you have any idea how to make the script flag the current_page_item css like wp_list_pages does?

Comment: I added this check. 
BUT … I strongly recommend not to link to the current page in the first place. No one has any benefit from such links. I replace all redundant links in my WP blogs with 

    <span class="current" title="You are here">Text</span>

See this article http://toscho.de/2009/deppenlink-entfernen/ (in German) for the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink('$link') ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php comments_number('0 Answers', '1 Answer', '% Answers'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```